# How do I convert a string into a vector of bytes in rust?

Tags: type-conversion, rust

That might be the dumbest Rustlang question ever but I promise I tried my best to find the answer in the documentation or any other place on the web.

I can convert a string to a vector of bytes like this:

```
let bar = bytes!("some string");
```

Unfortunately I can't do it this way

```
let foo = "some string";
let bar = bytes!(foo);
```

Because `bytes!` expects a string literal.

But then, how do I get my foo converted into a vector of bytes?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

[`(&str).as_bytes`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_bytes) gives you a view of a string as a `&[u8]` byte slice (that can be called on `String` since that derefs to `str`, and there's also [`String.into_bytes`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_bytes) will consume a `String` to give you a `Vec<u8>`.

Use the `.as_bytes` version if you don't need ownership of the bytes.

```rust
fn main() {
    let string = "foo";
    println!("{:?}", string.as_bytes()); // prints [102, 111, 111]
}
```

BTW, The [naming conventions for conversion functions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-wiki-backup/blob/master/Doc-detailed-release-notes.md#cast-naming-conventions) are helpful in situations like these, because they allow you to know approximately what name you might be looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you apply that to my example so that I have the equivalent of `bytes!(foo)` in `bar`? I tried `let bar = (&foo).as_bytes` but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Being more specific it gives me this compile error:

*attempted to take value of method `as_bytes` on type `&'static str`*

Comment: You have to call it with `()`s: `foo.as_bytes()`. I edited an example into my answer.

Comment: Oh, nooooo. I honestly feel like the dumbest man on StackOverflow now. THANKS!

Comment: @huon-dbaupp Compiling your example with Rust 1.2 gives ```the trait `core::fmt::Display` is not implemented for the type `[u8]` [E0277]```. Does that mean your answer needs to be updated to change `{}` with `{:?}`?

Comment: To be clear, the resulting bytes are in UTF-8 encoding, because that's how Rust stores `str` and `String`. (Conceptually, it doesn't make any sense to talk about the "bytes of a string" without talking about encoding.)

Answer (score 26):

To expand the answers above. Here are a few different conversions between types.

`&str` to `&[u8]`:

```rust
let my_string: &str = "some string";
let my_bytes: &[u8] = my_string.as_bytes();
```

`&str` to `Vec<u8>`:

```rust
let my_string: &str = "some string";
let my_bytes: Vec<u8> = my_string.as_bytes().to_vec();
```

`String` to `&[u8]`:

```rust
let my_string: String = "some string".to_owned();
let my_bytes: &[u8] = my_string.as_bytes();
```

`String` to `Vec<u8>`:

```rust
let my_string: String = "some string".to_owned();
let my_bytes: Vec<u8> = my_string.into_bytes();
```

Specifying the variable type is optional in all cases. Just added to avoid confusion.

Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5ad228e45a38b4f097bbbba49100ecfc

Answer (score -1):

```
 `let v1: Vec<u8> = string.encode_to_vec();`
 `let v2: &[u8]   = string.as_bytes();`
```

two work difference, in some of library use  ownership of bytes !! if you use as_bytes() see compiler error: must be static.

for example: `tokio_uring::fs::File::write_at()`
get a ownership of bytes !!

but if you need borrowing , use as_bytes()