# How to change a String into a Vec and can also modify Vec's value in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to change a String into a vector of bytes and also modify its value, I have looked up and find [How do I convert a string into a vector of bytes in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850486/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-a-vector-of-bytes-in-rust)
but this can only get a reference and I cannot modify the vector. I want `a` to be 0, `b` to be 1 and so on, so after changing it into bytes I also need to subtract 97. Here is my attempt:

```
fn main() {
    let s: String = "abcdefg".to_string();
    let mut vec = (s.as_bytes()).clone();
    println!("{:?}", vec);
    for i in 0..vec.len() {
        vec[i] -= 97;
    }
    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

but the compiler says

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `vec[_]`, which is behind a `&` reference
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You could get a `Vec<u8>` out of the `String` with the [`into_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_bytes) method. An even better way, though, may be to iterate over the `String`'s bytes with the [`bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.bytes) method, do the maths on the fly, and then collect the result:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "abcdefg";
    let vec: Vec<u8> = s.bytes().map(|b| b - b'a').collect();
    println!("{:?}", vec); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}
```

But as @SvenMarnach correctly points out, this won't re-use `s`'s buffer but allocate a new one. So, unless you need `s` again, the `into_bytes` method will be more efficient.

Comment: Whether iterating is "even better" really depends. Using `into_bytes()` and modifying the vector will reuse the same buffer, while the iterator approach will allocate a new buffer.

Comment: True! I guess OP's use of `clone` must have made me think that they'd need the original `String` again, but that was an unfounded assumption on my part.

Comment: That's a valid point though, your method doesn't need the `to_string`.

Comment: @Caesar Also true haha. I guess that way you _do_ save the allocation.

Comment: Right, if it's a static string, you can avoid the first allocation, but if the string comes from a different source in the actual use case, it's probably already allocated. We are basically speculating here. :)

Comment: re @SvenMarnach "*the iterator approach will allocate a new buffer*"—actually, if one were to owning-iterate the underlying vector, such as with `.into_bytes().into_iter().map(|b| b - b'a').collect()`, then (subject to the vagaries of the optimisation gods) stdlib can actually be [smart enough](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/spec_from_iter.rs.html#37-64) to [perform the iteration in-place](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=ef9817d8c3ce29b18dc9b70d34c9d344).

Comment: @eggyal Of course I was referring to the code in this answer, which is not using `into_bytes()`, and which did allocate twice (before it was editied).

Answer (score 3):

To understand what's going on, check the type of the `vec` variable. If you don't have an IDE/editor that can display the type to you, you can do this:

```rust
let mut vec: () = (s.as_bytes()).clone();
```

The resulting error message is explanative:

```
3 |     let mut vec: () = (s.as_bytes()).clone();
  |                  --   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found `&[u8]`
```

So, what's happening is that the `.clone()` simply cloned the reference returned by `as_bytes()`, and didn't create a `Vec<u8>` from the `&[u8]`. In general, you can use `.to_owned()` in this kind of case, but in this specific case, using `.into_bytes()` on the `String` is best.

Answer (score 3):

Strings in Rust are encoded in UTF-8. The (safe) interface of the `String` type enforces that the underlying buffer always is valid UTF-8, so it can't allow direct arbitrary byte modifications. However, you can convert a `String` into a `Vec<u8>` using the [`into_bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_bytes) mehod. You can then modify the vector, and potentially convert it back to a string using [`String::from_utf8()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8) if desired. The last step will verify that the buffer still is vaid UTF-8, and will fail if it isn't.

Instead of modifying the *bytes* of the string, you could also consider modifying the *characters*, which are potentially encoded by multiple bytes in the UTF-8 encoding. You can iterate over the characters of the string using the `chars()` method, convert each character to whatever you want, and then collect into a new string, or alternatively into a vector of integers, depending on your needs.